# What does getCurrentPosition return?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

This is what I have:

```
   var position;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

  function onSuccess(pos) {
position = { latitude: pos.coords.latitude, longitude: pos.coords.longitude} ;
//position = { latitude:43.465099,longitude:-80.520344};
  }

  function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }


  var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.latitude,position.longitude
      ),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true
  };
```

When I use the commented out line, the program works fine and it zooms to the hardcoded location. When I use the pos.coords line, nothing happens. Am I calling it wrong? Am I not able to just put it in my variable like that or does it return something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using the result properly but I would encode the JSON a bit differently:

```
position = { "latitude": pos.coords.latitude, 
             "longitude": pos.coords.longitude};
```